# Robotium and intellij idea core library compile error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, robotium

I'm trying to add Robotium tests to my android project in intelli-j idea via maven. When I try to compile it though it just gives the following error

```
Android Dex: [robotium] trouble processing "javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class":
Android Dex: [robotium] Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Android Dex: [robotium] when not building a core library.
Android Dex: [robotium] This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Android Dex: [robotium] in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Android Dex: [robotium] Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Android Dex: [robotium] core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Android Dex: [robotium] going on.
Android Dex: [robotium] However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Android Dex: [robotium] namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Android Dex: [robotium] from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Android Dex: [robotium] assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
...
```

Things I have tried to solve this

1) Adding Robotium via maven to an empty project and a sample Robotium app. There was no change.

2) Under "project structure" I tried changing the scope of the Robotium library. I could get it to compile that way but then just ended up with NoClassDefFoundError errors. Not what I want.

3) tried using a previous version of Robotium - no change.

4) Searching google I came across this:

```
Nov 14 01:32:50 <xastey> I asked this ealier but got sidetrack with other work so ....
 I'm getting "trouble processing "javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.class" " while
trying to compile my project.. anyone ran into this problem?
        ...

Nov 14 01:37:01 <xastey> nvm.. had to remove com.google.android:android dependency
```

Looking into the maven classes from com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:4.3 it does import

```
android-4.0.1.2.jar
```

Now naturally I already have the android platform included in my project. Could this be the problem? That the android platform is included twice?
This also seems to suggest support of this hypothesis [Android 4.0 Eclipse compilation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922103/android-4-0-eclipse-compilation-failed)

If so how can I fix this? There does not seem to be a way to edit the jars of a maven import in the IDE. Do I have to manually edit a pom file? I have only used the IDE for dependencies so I have almost no knowledge/experience beyond that.

Of course maybe I am completely on the wrong track here. Any advise/input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It turns out the maven package com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:4.3 was the problem. It has about 10 different jars in it. These extra jars appear to be the issue. I have no idea what they are for as it turns out they are not necessary.

When I just manually include only the robotium-solo-4.3.jar in my project robotium works with no issue.